# Como utilizar o f2py utilizando mais de um arquivo .f90 e utilizando a dassl.f?

Tags: python, fortran

Sou iniciante em F2PY e estou tentando utilizá-lo em um programa em Fortran bem complexo que possui várias subrotinas em arquivos separados e um delas é a dassl.f. Acredito que o meu problema seja com ela. Existe alguma limitação quanto ao seu uso com o F2PY? (Uso linux)

Comando no terminal:

```
$ f2py -c -m Reator Variaveis.F90 Principal.F90 Jacob.F90 Res.F90 PontoBolha.F90 dassl.F Conversao.F90 Massas_Molares.F90 PropFisicas.F90 Taxa.F90 gel.F90 Vazao.F90
```

Última resposta do terminal:

> error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2
>   -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/tmp/tmp5u6gg0ww/src.linux-x86_64-3.5 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c /tmp/tmp5u6gg0ww/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/Reatormodule.c -o
>   /tmp/tmp5u6gg0ww/tmp/tmp5u6gg0ww/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/Reatormodule.o"
>   failed with exit status 1

Variaveis.F90 é um MODULE e todos os outros são SUBROUTINES.